# How to get the stored procedure result set value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I create a stored proc A that calls another proc B, which returns a list of the result set.

How I can use these result set values in my proc A as I have to use this result set value one by one to pass to other part of the proc A.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Re-usable SQL Server stored procedures; nesting; global variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254682/re-usable-sql-server-stored-procedures-nesting-global-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform an `INSERT INTO` to insert the results of the stored procedure into a (temporary) table. You can then use a select statement to process these results.

```
INSERT INTO SomeTableThatMatchesTheSproc
EXEC YourStoredProcedure;

SELECT * FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Means i have to store the result in some kind of temp result set after that i can use the result value.

Comment: Correct. If you want to use results, you might want to consider using a SQL user-defined function instead of a stored procedure.